# How to display and hide table view cells in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with two different custom cell. One cell have few textfields data and other also have different textfield data,here i need to collapse and hide the each cell. i don't know how to do this.Please let me know.

https://maniacdev.com/2013/03/an-open-source-ios-control-allowing-you-to-create-great-looking-collapsible-lists-without-uitableview

Please refer the above link, i want the same in swift.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which cells are you talking about, please provide more info and post some code for what you've done

Comment: Can you please add more details. It is not possible to solve problem with such lesser info. What exactly you want to do  and what you have done.

Comment: https://maniacdev.com/2013/03/an-open-source-ios-control-allowing-you-to-create-great-looking-collapsible-lists-without-uitableview

Please refer the above link, i want the same in swift.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want to hide one of your UITableViewCells?

Ill think the easiest way is to add some more information to your "Row Data Array".

For example:

You have 10 Columns, and you want to hide 4 Specific Column. You have a function called "getRowData" - this returns (when no filter is selected) all 10 Rows. When you tap on a button, you could change your "getRowData" function to return only the 4 Rows you want.

With the example you showed above - you want some collapsible Lists, based on an UITableViewController.

So you have (In this example) 3 Main Categories - and if the User click on one "Title" you want to expand the list for this Category.

So you could use Sections - create a Section for each Category. Then implement something like this:

// create a main variable for your "activated Category"

```
var enabledCategory:Int = 0 // you could add i base value

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();

        enabledCategory = indexPath.row;
....
```

Check here which section was clicked by the user. If (for example "0" - so the first one, expand this section. So do something like this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(indexPath.section == enabledCategory) {
        return rows // return rows you want to show
    }
```

You need also to change the count of rows in here:

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 3
}
```

this should be (in your example) always 3.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
```

This depends on your section // Category

Comment: So funny =)))))