# How to animate cells with UIButton?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

[image: Here, you can see the section header buttons as "TEST HEADER"]

I want to collapse all the cells inside a section. I want to do that by tapping a button that I added in section header. Obviously, with an animation. Not just disappearing. I have an idea that, If I could just get the index path of the section, since I have constant number of cells inside every section, I can create a switch statement to animate cells with proper indexes.

Answer (score 3):

You could use beginUpdates/endUpdates block. You put the changes to your tableView which you want to happen animated into this block. (Don't call `[tableView reloadData]` inside the block though.)

For example, you write something like this in the section header button tap handler:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsWithIdexPaths:indexPathsToDelete 
                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

With this code rows with indexes `indexPathsToDelete` will disappear with `UITableViewRowAnimationTop` animation, but you can change animation type depending on your needs.

For more information see [WWDC2010 Video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/) "Mastering Table Views", especially Demo starting from 17:40.

Comment: I write an integer for indexPath, but It doesn't allow me to do. I am trying to call this function inside a button action.

Comment: `indexPathsToDelete` is array of index paths, so it should be something like this:`@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0], [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]]`

Answer (score 1):

1: assign action to header view (I'm sure there is a delegate callback for section tap, otherwise add TapGesture to the header view)

2: if you use auto layout the animate the height constraints of tabvleView otherwise the frame.height of tableView

Is there any efficient way? Maybe UITableView has undocking function built in :)

Comment: Can you explain the second the step, or give me some tutorial links or something? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I would add two tableView's in that ViewController. TestHeader would be a button that animates the table view height.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding custom animation for expanding/collapsing rows to the following UITableViewDelegate func may work...

optional func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)

Also, the following link provided a good solution for hiding table view cells/rows...

[How to display and hide table view cells in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28536691/how-to-display-and-hide-table-view-cells-in-swift)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

So if you use AutoLayout (and you should because it's great) then animation of let's say a UIView *contentView would look like this:

```
IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *contentViewHeightConstraint;
```

connect this Outlet in Interface Builder to the contentView's height contraint.

If you don't know contranits and autolayout, then youtube and practice for 2 weeks :)

```
- (void)moveViewsUp {
    [contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    int delta = 100;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIM_DURATION
                     animations: ^{
        contentViewHeightConstraint.constant = -delta;
        [contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
        completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}

- (void)moveViewsDown {
    [contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIM_DURATION
                     animations: ^{
        contentViewHeightConstraint.constant = 0;
        [contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    }
     completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
}
```